# Outlook new email to Excel row

Tags: c#, excel, email, outlook

I want to create a C# Console app (or a service - not sure how to develop a service yet) that:

1) Knows when a new email is received in Inbox>LOTALogs folder. This email is sent by a mobile application and includes an attachment and some issues that the customer experienced.

2) Takes the new email content, which is comma-separated, parses and appends the content into an Excel worksheet that already has the columns set up.

I managed to create:

1) The parser:

```
    public static string[] emailContentsArray()
    {
        string content = "Username = Customer1,User ID = 362592,Unit ID = 805618,Date = Mar 12, 2017,Device = Android LGE LG-H990,OS version = 7.0 (API 24),App version = 1.0.0.56,Description = some description,Message = some message";
        string[] contentArray = content.Split(',');

        // Case where date format includes another comma
        if (contentArray.Length > 10)
        {
            // Parsing headers
            contentArray[0] = contentArray[0].Substring(11);
            contentArray[1] = contentArray[1].Substring(10);
            contentArray[2] = contentArray[2].Substring(10);
            contentArray[3] = contentArray[3].Substring(7) + ", " + contentArray[4].Substring(1);
            contentArray[4] = contentArray[5].Substring(9);
            contentArray[5] = contentArray[6].Substring(13);
            contentArray[6] = contentArray[7].Substring(14);
            contentArray[7] = contentArray[8].Substring(14);
            contentArray[8] = contentArray[9].Substring(10);
            contentArray[9] = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(contentArray[i] + ",");
            }
        }
        //else
        //{

        //}
        return contentArray;
    }
```

2) Accessed the folder and counted the number of items:

```
    public static string[] emailContent()
    {
        string[] content = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder logFolder = null;

        app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        logFolder = app.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["LOTALogs"];
        int itemCount = logFolder.Items.Count;

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nFolder Name: {0}, Num Items: {1}\n", logFolder.Name, itemCount);

        return content;
    }
```

3) Opened and printed the contents of the spreadsheet:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        string path = "C:\\SomeUser\\BugReports";
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@path);
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        for (int i = 1; i <= xlRange.Row + xlRange.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Column + xlRange.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                    Console.Write("\r\n");

                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
            }
        }
        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am a little lost now :)

I  still need to:

1) Create an event listener (I think that's what it's called) so I can tell the email body parser to go fetch the email contents.

2) Extract the email body from the email.

Got this using

```
 Console.WriteLine(logFolder.Items[1].Body);
```

3) Take the email content and append it to the spreadsheet.

4) Should I create this as a Windows Service?

PS - I am not a developer, just fiddling around with code and trying to be as efficient as possible. I don't want to fill this spreadsheet out manually when there's a technological solution in sight. Please comment if you have any suggestions on being more efficient with the code and model it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks solid to me. I'd refrain from the service, but it greatly depends on your users. Unless your customer really wants to be "blind" from the whole process, it adds a lot of unwarranted complications.

As for appending to the spreadsheet...

```
int lastRow = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows;
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.Cells[lastRow + 1, 1];
xlRange.Value = stuffFromInbox;
```

If you're only adding the one item to the spreadsheet, this will work fine.  For mass read/write operations with the spreadsheet (like your "Opened and printed the contents of the spreadsheet"), it would be much more efficient to read the `Value` or `Value2` of the entire `Range` into a `object[,]`.  Then iterate through the local array.